# Using xsl:key function to pass parameters globally

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been dealing with using this xsl:key for a while. I can not reach the desired output and also I don't know where is the mistake.

Here is the example of xml(XSLT treated as xml):

```
<xsl:template mode="something" match="node">
    <xsl:variable name="node" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="example" select="example"/>
        <xsl:variable name="example" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:if test="not($node//*[matches(local-name(),$example)])">
            <xsl:call-template name="name">
                <xsl:with-param name="rule" select="'S140'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="other" select="'textValue'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="other" match="node">
    <xsl:call-template name="name">
        <xsl:with-param name="rule" select="'S150'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="other" select="'textValue'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template mode="another" match="anotherNode">
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="something">
            <xsl:variable name="example" select="path"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="name">
                <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'S140'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="content" select="$example"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="path0">
            <xsl:variable name="example"
                select="path1"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="name">
                <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'S145'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="content" select="$example"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="path2">
            <xsl:variable name="ele"
                select="path3"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="name">
                <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'S150'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="content" select="$example"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
</xsl:template>
```

and my external XML that I read values from.

```
<VALIDATION>
    <VALIDATION_STATE ATTR="S140">a</VALIDATION_STATE>
    <VALIDATION_STATE ATTR="S150">b</VALIDATION_STATE>
    <VALIDATION_STATE ATTR="S155">c</VALIDATION_STATE>
</VALIDATION>
```

and my XSLT:

```
    <xsl:key name="xslRuleCode" match="xsl:call-template[@name = 'name']" use="substring(xsl:with-param[1]/@select,2,4)"/>
    <xsl:param name="validation" select="document('validation.xml')"/>
<xsl:template match="xsl:template">
    <xsl:variable name="xslRule" select="key('xslRuleCode', .)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Documentation</xs:documentation>
        <attr_id>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('URL', $xslRule)"/>
        </attr_id>
        <description>
            <xsl:for-each select="$validation/VALIDATION/VALIDATION_STATE">
                <xsl:if test="@ATTR= $xslRule">
                    <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </description>
    </xs:annotation>
</xsl:template>
```

There are two values one in XML file(as XSLT format) and the other value is in external XML file.

The idea is reaching out these both elements, compare them and if they match write the value of element into related annotations.

Expected output is:

```
<xsl:template mode="something" match="node">
    <xsl:variable name="node" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="example" select="example"/>
        <xsl:variable name="example" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <xsl:if test="not($node//*[matches(local-name(),$example)])">
            <xsl:call-template name="name">
                <xsl:with-param name="rule" select="'S140'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="other" select="'textValue'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
 <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Documentation</xs:documentation>
        <attr_id>
            URL/S140
        </attr_id>
        <description>
            a
        </description>
<xsl:template mode="other" match="node">
    <xsl:call-template name="name">
        <xsl:with-param name="rule" select="'S150'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="other" select="'textValue'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Documentation</xs:documentation>
        <attr_id>
            URL/S150
        </attr_id>
        <description>
            b
        </description>
```

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

If I match with `<xsl:call-template>` instead of doing it in `<xsl:template>`
I am able to reach the values I want. But I dont want to create annotations after call-template, It has to be after each template.

```
<xsl:template match="xsl:call-template[@name = 'name']">
    <xsl:param name="xslRule" select="substring(xsl:with-param[1]/@select, 2, 4)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="ancestor::xsl:template/last()">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>documentation</xs:documentation>
                <rule_id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('URL', $xslRule)"/>
                </rule_id>
                <description>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$validation/VALIDATION/VALIDATION_STATE">
                <xsl:if test="@ATTR= $xslRule">
                    <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
                </description>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: When using the key you do `key('xslRuleCode', substring(@select, 2, 4))`, but this is in a template matching `xsl:template` and `xsl:template` elements do not have `select` attributes, so it is not clear what is intended here.... Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I am sure my Xpath is wrong or the way I use the xsl:key. So the idea is to read the "@select" from xsl:call-template/xsl:with-param and use it to compare with the value inside the external xml file "@attr" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `xsl:key` here. You would only need to do that if you were matching a named template, and wanted to get all `xsl:call-templates` what called it, for example.

I think your problem can be solved simply by doing this...

```
<xsl:variable name="xslRule" 
              select="substring((.//xsl:call-template/xsl:with-param[@name='rule'])[1]/@select, 2, 4)"/>
```

This assumes there is only one `xsl:call-template` in each template though.

EDIT: If you have multiple `xsl:call-template` statements in a template, and want an annotation for each after the main template itself, you can use `xsl:for-each`.

```
<xsl:template match="xsl:template">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select=".//xsl:call-template/xsl:with-param[1]/@select">
        <xsl:variable name="xslRule" select="." />
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Documentation</xs:documentation>
            <attr_id>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('URL', $xslRule)"/>
            </attr_id>
            <description>
                <xsl:for-each select="$validation/VALIDATION/VALIDATION_STATE">
                    <xsl:if test="@ATTR= $xslRule">
                        <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </description>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The thing is that if I use ".//" it selects all of the values at once, Which is not the desired solution by my side. I want to get the values recursively each time and compare with the other files value.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the expected result when there are two `xsl:call-template` statements within a single `xsl:template`? Thanks

Comment: If there are more than one <xsl:call-template> there will be just one result because the "@select" values are the same. It changes template to template not based on number of <xsl:call-templates>. The reason why I want to use <xsl:key> is: "//" selection is not working to compare values one by one here. Thats why I wanted to reach them with key.(I did it a while ago for another topic, But I could not fix this one now.

Comment: I've made a small edit to my answer. Note, the expression starts with `.//` and not `//`. The `.` at the start represents the context node, and so the expression will only look for `xsl:call-templates` under the current node.

Comment: Hi Thank you ! Tim, It works, Just a question, What if the multiple call-templates does have different codes, and I want to write annotations for each of them?

Comment: You could use an `xsl:for-each` to get each one. For example `<xsl:for-each select=".//xsl:call-template/xsl:with-param[@name='rule'])/@select">`

Comment: I actually did it, But it gets only the first one and repeats it for each.I think it is because of we defined the $xslRule as the first value of it always.

Comment: Is there any way to iterate one by one with ".//" selections, instead of choosing first one?I would definetely prefer the solution with <xsl:key> if you can provide, would be nice

Comment: Yes. Use `xsl:for-each`. If you can't get it to work, feel free to ask a whole new question. Thanks.

Comment: Tim, It creates the structure but always repeats the first call-template. It doesnt iterate through other call-templates. I use for-each and practically use the code you suggested, Could you please try as well please? thank you

Comment: You still need to match on `xsl:template`, and use an `xsl:for-each` inside that. I've made an edit to my answer to show how.

Comment: Okay, got it, my bad I just changed "." to substring(.,2,4) and it works now. Thank you Tim.